# Custom nested checkbox in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would need help in creating this image below using react hooks. I am looking to achieve the following

1. Selecting all section
2. Selecting a single section (e.g  `First section` or `Second section`)
3. Selecting items (e.g select `item 1` and `item 4`)

[image]

Comment: What kind of help? It looks like a typical recursive problem (noting that there are components that do this kind of thing already and include custom renderers).

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this.  Did you try creating code? Once you have code that does not work maybe you can post the question.  I would create  a model with nested array fields like Dave has suggested already.